# How to create a hook which fires when I pause typing in Emacs?

Tags: emacs

I want to implement a hook which will work similar to Automatic LaTeX plugin for Vim: when I pause typing in emacs org mode, hook should fire and do (org-beamer-export-to-pdf t) in background.

How to create such a hook?

Comment: Some random ideas: `auto-save-hook` or `run-with-idle-timer`.

Comment: Seems like a lot of overhead, and also seems like you risk a lot of errors if you pause typing in the middle of entering a syntactic form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @legoscia for the idea. Solved my problem using [Real auto saving for emacs](http://www.litchie.net/programs/real-auto-save.html) script with slightly modified real-auto-save function:

```
(defun real-auto-save()
  (interactive)
  (if real-auto-save-p
      (progn
    (save-excursion
      (dolist (elem real-auto-save-alist)
        (set-buffer elem)
        (if (and (buffer-file-name) (buffer-modified-p))
        (progn
          (write-file (buffer-file-name))
                   (if (boundp 'org-beamer-mode)
                       (org-beamer-export-to-pdf t))
                  )))))))
```

In my init.el file:

```
(require 'real-auto-save)
(add-hook 'org-mode-hook 'turn-on-real-auto-save)
(setq real-auto-save-interval 2)
```

Everything is working perfect, no overhead or error messages.